Using the loop counter of the main program inside the module as a variable
The text of my program is similar to this, and I have used the loop counter as a variable in the module, but it gives an error in the output.?!!
main program:
for i in range(3):
    import day

module:
x = 3 + i
print(x)

error: name 'i' is not defined
I want to use the loop counter in another module, how can I do it?

To use a variable that is defined in another module, import it from that module.  What is the difficulty?

If i would be created in another module you could import anothermodule and then access it with anothermodule.i but from the main script to a module would be rather complicated.

Modules don't share variables (i.e. scope), so the module that you import will never be able to access the variables in the module that imports it. (At least not implicitly.)
Additionally, importing a module more than once has no effect since modules are cached. (There are some caveats to this, but they're not relevant.)
Instead, what you should do is define a function in day that takes a parameter, which we could call i, but I'm going to call it k to avoid confusion. Then in the main program, import the function from day and pass i as an argument.
Main program:
from day import some_function

for i in range(3):
    some_function(i)

day.py:
def some_function(k):
    x = 3 + k
    print(x)

Output from main program:
3
4
5


"will never be able to access" - After import __main__ it can access  __main__.i just fine.

@nocomment Huh! I've never heard of that before. Edited to mention that. Still, __main__ is only the top-level module. What I had in mind was any importing module in a hierarchy of imports.

Try this approach:
Create a function inside the module which accepts i, which then will be called from the main program.
In main.py:
from day_module import day_func
for i in range(3):
    day_func(i)

In module day_module.py:
def day_func(i):
    x = 3 + i
    print(x)

Output:
3
4
5

